# Is there a way to coalesce repeated numbers in a list using streams in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

e.g.#1 
`[1, 1, 1, 2, 22, 35, 35, 120, 320]` ==>> `[3, 2, 22, 70, 120, 320]`

note how repeated consecutive 1's and 35's are coalesced to 3 and 70 respectively

e.g.#2
`[1,1,3,1,1]` ==>> `[2,3,2]`

Comment: Coalesce means to come together and create a single, larger sum or value. He is using it properly.

Comment: coalesce means merging several items into a single unit right ? Here i'm asking if i can merge repeated numbers into a single number(which is the sum of those numbers).

Comment: But it wouldn't work for this : [0,0,0,0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0] => [0, 3, 0]

Comment: What should be result of `[1,1,3,1,1]`? Should it be `[2,3,2]` or `[4,3]` (or maybe something else)?

Comment: it would be [2, 3, 2]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Stream.of(1, 1, 1, 2, 22, 35, 35, 120, 320)
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(
              Function.identity(),
              Function.identity(),
              Integer::sum,
              LinkedHashMap::new
          ))
          .values()
          .forEach(System.out::println);
```

In the case the you posted a comment, you would need a custom collector, actually:

```
static class Custom implements Collector<Integer, List<Integer>, List<Integer>> {

    private Integer match;

    @Override
    public Supplier<List<Integer>> supplier() {
        return ArrayList::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<List<Integer>, Integer> accumulator() {
        return (list, x) -> {
            int lastIndex = list.size() - 1;
            if (match != null && match.equals(x)) {
                list.set(lastIndex, list.get(lastIndex) + x);
            } else {
                match = x;
                list.add(x);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<List<Integer>> combiner() {
        return (left, right) -> {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not for parallel");
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<List<Integer>, List<Integer>> finisher() {
        return Function.identity();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Set.of();
    }
}
```

And usage would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream.of(1, 1, 3, 1, 1)
          .collect(new Custom())
          .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: But it wouldn't work for this : [0,0,0,0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0] => [0, 3, 0]

Answer (score 3):

Why bother using streams when you can do it with a simple for loop and an if-else block?

```
   List<Integer> list = List.of(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
   List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
   Integer curr = list.get(0);
   Integer sum = 0;
   for(Integer i : list){
       if(i.equals(curr)){
           sum += i;
       }
       else{
           result.add(sum);
           sum = i;
           curr = i;
       }
   }
   result.add(sum);
   System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: I was wondering if it could be done in a few lines  using some fancy reduce function or something.

Comment: imho, Streams are terrible for a use case when you need to compare elements at specific positions. This `for` loop is way cleaner.

Comment: @AniruthN if you only needed to count occurrences, you could do it with `input.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))` then iterate on it. But 1) entries would not be sorted 2) it would not work on entries like `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: Unfortunately, Streams are like regular expressions.  They both are written to support many different situations where using loops and simple parsers are more efficient and quite often, not difficult to write.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using a stack.

```
public static List<Integer> coalesce(List<Integer> list) {
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    stack.addAll(list);
    List<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<>();
    int sum = 0;
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
       int val = stack.pop();
       sum += val;
       if (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() != val) {
          sums.add(0,sum);
          sum = 0;
       }
    }
    sums.add(0,sum);
    return sums;
}
```