# Java Stream - Type Inference issue inside a Collector

Tags: java, generics, java-stream, type-inference, collectors

I have a similar use case to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60568485/split-a-list-into-sublists-by-grouping-only-repeated-elements-that-are-adjac) stack overflow question and was trying to use it without storing the result in a `List<List<String>>` but instead call `stream()` on it.

I have a strange compile time error if I don't assign it to `List<List<String>>` because of type mismatch. To reproduce the issue, just comment out the assignment to output.

The question is why is this compile error occurs? And how to fix it?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<String> input = Arrays.asList("RED", "RED", "BLUE", "BLUE", "BLUE", "BLUE", "RED", "RED");
    List<List<String>> output =  // if this line commented it doesn't compile
        input.stream()
            .collect(Collector.of(
                ArrayList::new,
                (accumulator, item) -> {
                    if (accumulator.isEmpty()) {
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        list.add(item);
                        accumulator.add(list);
                    } else {
                        List<String> last = accumulator.get(accumulator.size() - 1);
                        if (last.isEmpty() || last.get(0).equals(item)) {
                            last.add(item);
                        } else {
                            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                            list.add(item);
                            accumulator.add(list);
                        }
                    }
                },
                (left, right) -> {
                    left.addAll(right);
                    return left;
                }
            ));
}
```

My idea was to use it like:

```
input.stream()
    .collect(Collector.of(.....))
    .stream()
    .(and do something else)
```

Comment: If you have s stream, why collect it into a List, then turn that into a stream immediately? This strikes me as a bit of an XY problem.

Comment: "// if this line commented it doesn't compile" Because it is not a statement :) 
plain 1+1 wont compile neither, but int i=1+1 will;

Comment: @Antoniossss I don't think so. `input.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet())` will compile just fine and I can call `stream()` on the resulting set without assigning it to a set beforehand

Comment: @Chris That is exactly what I am trying to do: not store it in an intermediate `List<List<String>>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions in Java have no type by itself. They are *poly expressions*. It means their type should be inferred from the context. It applies for all arguments of the `Collector.of()`.

`List<List<String>> output` - provides the [target type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types), without it, type inference mechanism has no clue what type of object your Collector is expected to produce.

To make the code compile you can use the *type-witness* while calling `Collector.<all the types of functions used in collector here>of()`.

The simplest way to make this stream-statement compile is to provide explicit types of arguments of the *accumulator*:

```
(List<List<String>> accumulator, String item) ->
     {
          ...
     },
```

Comment: Thank you. With your help I got it working and can chain my `stream()` call.